# Pass a file with filepaths to Python in Ubuntu terminal to analyze each file?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, command-line-arguments

I have a text file with file paths:

```
path1
path2
path3
...
path100000000
```

I have my python script app.py that should run on each file (path1, path2 ...)

Please advise what is the best way to do it?

Should I just get it as argument, and then:

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    main_function(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work, except `readlines()` doesn't remove newline characters.

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        main_function(line.strip())
```

**Note: The above code assumes the file is in the same directory as the python script file.
You are using context managers. Hence, place the code inside the context.

So according to your comment,

1. If you want to pass filename where you will read the file contents in the `main_function`, then the above code will work.
2. If you want to read the file and then pass the file contents, then you will have to modify the above code to first read the content and then pass it to the function

```
    with open(input_file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            main_function(open(line.strip(), "r").read())
```

**Note: the above function will read the whole file as a single string (text)

Comment: and if I want to add an option that it's the actual path to the file? How can I add it?
Sometimes it can be the file itself

Comment: @SteveS I have addressed your questions in above edit

Comment: Thanks but if I need my program to identify the case (single file or file with contents - other files paths) maybe I need to do it with:
```parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                               
parser.add_argument("--file", "-f", type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument("--file_list", "-fl", type=str, required=True)```
@bigbounty

Comment: @SteveS Accept the answer if it has answered your question